RTX 4080 16GB Super not recognised by Ubuntu 22.04
My new RTX 4080 16GB Super is not recognised by Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed the 550 driver using the script. lspci does not list it. I have installed many cards in the past and I'm certain it's physically installed correctly. Anyone help, please?

The 550 driver is available from the graphics-drivers PPA.  Your mention of a "script" makes me think you have used some other source, which may or may not be well integrated with Ubuntu. Purge the nvidia stuff you installed and get from the PPA.

Thank you for your reply. I used the recommended install script NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-545.29.06.run from the NVidia site, 545 not 550. Could this be the problem do you think please?

Yes, that's probably the problem. The 545 driver is available in the standard repos, so you don't even need the graphica-drivers PPA.  22.04 uses the hwe packages to get the 6.5 kernel, and that uses gcc-12, which isn't the default (gcc-11), so maybe the driver build fails. The Ubuntu install brings in the gcc-12 as a dependency, so it works, and survives kernel/driver updates.

It was the configuration of the power connectors in the end.
